# Android ListView's setOnItemClickListener from PopupWindow not called

Tags: java, android, popupwindow

I'm trying to show a ListView from a PopupWindow. but when I'm try to call ListView's setOnItemClickListener nothing to haapen. Here It Java file

**PopupWindowActivity.java**

```
public class PopupWindowActivity extends Activity {
    String[] data = { "DATA 1", "DATA 2", "DATA 3", "DATA 4", "DATA 5", "DATA 6" };
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a);
    final Button btnOpenPopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openpopup);
    btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            ListView listView = (ListView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data));
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("Item Clicked");
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }
            });

            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnOpenPopup, 20, -5);

        }
    });
}
```

}

Here it is first xml file
**a.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/openpopup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Open Popup Window" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here it inflate xml file
**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/recording"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100sp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: can try  listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyBannerActivity.this,  ? instead of getApplicationContext(),

Comment: @ Dheeresh Singh: as it is. nothing happen

Comment: Button click event is working but listview's item click listner is not working

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just one minor change in your code and BOOOM your code will listen to you list click event

```
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,true);
```

You forget to mention **focusable** setting **true** in **PopupWindow** constructor.

Comment: Oh, right, of course Android. Why would I ever assume that a PopupWindow would not be focusable by default like every other view I used. Man I'm such an idiot sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

had the same problem, but in my case `setFocusble(false)` was required (and using `ListPopupWindow` was not a solution in my case as a lot of stuff in the project already used base `PopupWindow`'s functionality including extending).

If someone in the same situation there is a kind of workaround based on bug discusson [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414) (post #9)

The main idea is that `ListView`'s hierarchy is still receives touch events so we can manually trigger `onItemClick()`.

However this approach is not 100% identical to real `ListView`'s touch handling (like there is no glow of selection while tapping a row) this done pretty well for me for the moment.

If someone has more precise solution of this problem, please share.

So, here is complete `Adapter`'s code which can be used with `ListView` inside `PopupWindow` which is `setFocusable(false)`:

private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ListView mOwningListView;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> objects, ListView listView) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objects);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mOwningListView = listView;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.font_pick_row, null);
    }
    // this is the key point of workaround
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*
             *  as every row is still receiving their touches
             *  we can use this to manually trigger onItemClick
             *  since it doesn't firing in popupWindow.setFocusable(false)  
             */
            mOwningListView.getOnItemClickListener().onItemClick(mOwningListView, v, position, getItemId(position));

        }
    });
    //... other stuff
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: this looks like the better answer whenever you are dealing with a keyboard. Thanks for this idea!

Comment: Glad it helped! Consider up-voting if you think this answer is helpful so others can reach this solutions as well

Comment: This is the answer to remain "setFocusble(false)"!

Answer (score 0):

May this help you
.

Declare listview and list onClickListener outside the button ClickListener.