# Android how to create custom listview in quick action

Tags: android, listview, quickaction

I am trying to create quick action with listview but i didn't find solution for that.

Comment: Are you looking for quick action dialog/bar ??

Comment: i want listview in quick action dialog.

Comment: @Roshni: Did you notice my answer?

Comment: You can use QuickActionDialog or you can also use PopupWindow with your custom view.

Comment: Here is question with listview inside popup window. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11243564/582571

Comment: If you want listview why dont you try [`context menu`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) or create popup window on longClickEvent like Android Coader suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this site,

http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2011_11_01_archive.html

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/